# Order sql table by descending order in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Since the Id column is ordered by asc order, I want to change the ordering to desc order. I have following table [image]

I'm using following code in order to perform the desc ordering, but nothing happens in the table.

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string columnName = textBox9.Text;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Navn, Varenr, Antal, Enhed, Priseksklmoms, Konto FROM ProduktTable ORDER BY [" + columnName +
             "] DESC", cn))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

I'm writing the column name "Id" in textBox9, and the ExecuteNonQuery method returns a "-1" every time it is triggered. Why doesn't the table perform the desired sorting ?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.**

Since you use `SELECT` statement, so..

By the way, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.